# waiting for take from LinkedBlockingQueue in play 2.x java

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm using play framework 2.2.3
some said use Java API to spin new thread (Runnable)..
some said use Akka...

I want to create a function solely process for the Queue. So, it forever waiting for item in the queue.
If got item, it will process and waiting again.

e.g.
q = new LinkedBlockingQueueString

String s = q.take()

Should i use new thread or Akka.system().scheduler().scheduleOnce?

Comment: It is very hard to help with this vague information about what you are trying to achieve. Try to describe more details what you are trying to do!

Comment: I'm trying to read SSE streaming from Scala use Iteratee (but, i'm still new to scala) and put(q.offer) into LinkedBlockingQueue. Once LinkedBlockingQueue filled, q.take() will triggered. So, I need a seperate thread in java to cater for q.take() and process it(biz logic + db stuff). Then, wait for next chunk of string. This will be infinite loop.